# Failed to load resource: Could not connect to the server

Tags: node.js, express, web-applications, ibm-cloud, devops

Hey I am working on bluemix and using it to deploy the server. I am getting the following error on my webpage console: Failed to load resource: Could not connect to the server.

My code is as follows:

```
/*eslint-env node*/
var express = require('express');
var cfenv = require('cfenv');
var app = express();
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
cfenv.getAppEnv();
var http = require('http');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

var watson = require('watson-developer-cloud');
// parse application/x-www-form-urlencoded
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));

// parse application/json
app.use(bodyParser.json());


app.set('port', process.env.VCAP_APP_PORT || 6004);
app.set('ip', process.env.VCAP_APP_HOST || "localhost");

//Default REST Call for Testing
app.post('/hello', function(req, res) {
    console.log("It comes here!" + res.statusCode);
    var language_translation = watson.language_translation({
    username: 'my usrename',
    password: 'my password',
    version: 'v2'
    });

    language_translation.translate({
        text: req.body.message,
        source: 'en',
        target: req.body.language
    }, function(err, translation) {
    if(err) {
        console.log(err);
    } else {
        console.log(translation);
        res.send(translation.translations[0].translation);
    }
    });
});

app.get('/hello', function(request, response) {
    console.log("Hello!");
    response.send("Hello World");
});

app.listen(app.get('port'),app.get('ip'), function() {
    console.log("Server is listening on port "+app.get('port')+" and ip "+app.get('ip'));

    console.log("Hello Boiz!!! Printed on Screen");
});
```

Could someone please help me!!! 
Thanks

Comment: have you tried to add module.exports = app ?

Comment: Where do I add this?

Comment: at the end of your code, after app.listen ...

Comment: Didn't work. Even in localhost it fails to work

Comment: I realized the url i was sending to was wrong. How do I get the url format in bluemix?

Comment: @and_noob update your question with exactly what you want to achieve? you said 1 thing in question but other in comments.

Comment: @and_noob what do you get when you do this: `cf logs --recent`

Answer (score 0):

I see that your are trying to use IBM Watson's Language translation service. Here is a sample demo for the same: [Watson Language Translation Service](https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/language-translation-nodejs/blob/master/app.js)

Hope this helps.